# CCD resolutions in camera

Tags: ccd

I would like to know what are the available (industry standard) CCD sensor resolutions for cameras in the visible light. What is the highest CCD resolution that can be found in the industry?

Comment: For still or movie pictures capture?

Comment: For movies, filming at 30 and 60 Hz.

Comment: You could also do something like [ARGUS-IS](https://str.llnl.gov/AprMay11/vaidya.html), which tiles lots of smaller chips to get an extremely high resolution (>1GPixel). It's not quite 30 or 60FPS (~12FPS supposedly), but you can probably get higher FPS using less cameras.

Comment: I'm looking for specifications of individual sensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixel size and the area that they are occupied is the key parameters of a CCD sensor Dynamic Range, the SNR, the Spacial Resolution and the Modulation Transfer Function (with a given optics).

However if pixel size is reduced, sensitivity to light reduced accordingly. So there is a clear tradeoff between spatial resolution and light sensitivity.
So be cautious when read pixel size. Some manufacturers also use the sub-sample pixel but this is done after some process.

With the CMOS APS technology of 0.3μm (that was some years ago and I don’t know if it is changed), the optimal pixel size is 6.5μm.  That is 35 line pairs per mm Nyqist limit (i.e befor aliasing).
Technologies like 0.17μm may be allow down to about 4μ pixels.

High resolution industry standards -especially for medical applications- is 2.5k x 2.5k and 4k x4k.

A good list is [here](http://www.adept.net.au/cameras/ultraColour.shtml)

Comment: I found the KAE-02150 (interline), which provide a 1080p and 60 FPS. However, I don't want to be limited to 1080p at this frame rate. I've still not found something that can beat that.

Comment: Also, is the CMOS technology better for providing higher FPS at higher sensor resolution?

Comment: @m_power Traditionally CCD sensors offer higher dynamic range and resolution (i.e quality), and CMOS high number of pixels per second (i.e frame rate). The biggest advantage of CMOS is the speed of development since this process used for μprocessors, memories etc. resulting a fast approacing CMOS sensors the quality that CCD offering. See www.cmosis.com. A simple test is to compare a freeze frame of a motion captured by a CCD and a CMOS sensor.

Answer (score 0):

This one, for instance, http://www.jai.com/en/products/sp-20000-pmcl will give you 5k x 4k (20 Mpixel) at 30 fps.

ETA: This is a monochrome camera. Do you need color?

Comment: Yes, I do need colors.

Comment: And I'm looking for CCD type, not CMOS.

Comment: Why do you care about the underlying technology rather than the results?

Comment: Because I'm looking for the available technology before choosing a specific CCD sensor.